# Need to get htaccess file to support different paths

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webapp that users access via dynamic subdomains like user1.example.com. 
These are handled via public_html/example.com/index.php

How do I get requests to www.example.com and example.com to load public_html/example.com/www/index.php instead?

I tried using a rule to rewrite all www.example.com to example.com, but the L parameter doesn't seem to be doing what I thought it would do. I can see that it redirects to example.com, but it appears that it tries to load public_html/example.com/index.php instead of public_html/example.com/www/index.php.

Here is my current file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/www/index.php [R=301,L]

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```